# Determine angle between 3 coordinates

Tags: javascript, math

As you can see in my screenshot i try to calculate the angle between the coordinates AB and BC, in this case the angle is obviously 90°. But how can i determine this angle with javascript code?

[image: I try to determine the angle between AB and BC]

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763392/how-to-calculate-in-javascript-angle-between-3-points) and tried the accepted solution, but i always get `1.57`instead of 90 like i expected. I rewrote the original function because i did not understood how to pass my parameters to it.

Please excuse my bad paint and math skills.

```js
 function find_angle(Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy)
 {
  var AB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Bx-Ax,2) + Math.pow(By-Ay,2));    
  var BC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Bx-Cx,2) +  Math.pow(By-Cy,2)); 
  var AC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Cx-Ax,2) +  Math.pow(Cy-Ay,2));
  
  return Math.acos((BC*BC+AB*AB-AC*AC) / (2*BC*AB));
 }
 var angle = find_angle
    (
     4 ,  //Ax
     3 ,  //Ay
     
     4 ,  //Bx
     2 ,  //By
     
     0 ,  //Cx
     2  //Cy
    )
    
 alert ( angle );
```

Comment: Easy if you understand vectors.  Use the dot or cross product.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, i will inform about it. I learned about vectors a few years ago in school but i already forgot everything...

Comment: why do you expect 90? you mean 90°? [that's exactly what you get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)), but in radians

Comment: Yes, ofc i mean 90°. Thanks

Comment: computers tend to work in radians unless you tell them to convert a number to degrees.

Comment: Every language I know uses radians, not degrees.

Comment: hehe, sounds like function find_gold(), treasure hunters of javascript...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is given in *radians* in that thread.

1.57 radians is 90 degrees (pi/2). You can convert the answer to degrees by multiplying it with 180/pi.

```js
A = { x: 4, y: 3 };
B = { x: 4, y: 2 };
C = { x: 0, y: 2 };

alert(find_angle(A,B,C));

function find_angle(A,B,C) {
    var AB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B.x-A.x,2)+ Math.pow(B.y-A.y,2));    
    var BC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B.x-C.x,2)+ Math.pow(B.y-C.y,2)); 
    var AC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(C.x-A.x,2)+ Math.pow(C.y-A.y,2));
    
    return Math.acos((BC*BC+AB*AB-AC*AC) / (2*BC*AB)) * (180 / Math.PI);   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `v = A - B` and `w = C - B`. Then the angle between `v` and `w` is the angle between `vx+i*vy` and `wx+i*wy` is the argument of `w/v` (as complex numbers) which is up to positive factors

```
(wx+i*wy)*(vx-i*vy)=wx*vx+wy*vy+i*(wy*vx-wx*vy).
```

The argument of a complex number is best computed using the `atan2` function, thus

```
angle = atan2( wy*vx-wx*vy , wx*vx+wy*vy)
```

As previously said, the angles used are in radians, so you have to convert to degrees if desired.